# Accessing object in referenced xaml file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, preferences

I have a project (c#, wpf) and I'm referencing to a Lib that contains another xaml-file (other namespace of course).
Then I'm creating an object of a class defined in the Lib:

```
DialogStandard newWindow = new DialogStandard();
newWindow.Title = "my title";
newWindow.mainLabel.Content = "my label";
```

DialogStandard is of type window (of course with objects defined in xaml)

```
public partial class DialogStandard : Window
```

I'm able to access the Title (newWindow.Title = "my title") because Title is an attribute of class Window.
But I can't access mainLabel because that is defined in xaml file of DialogStandard:

```
<Label Margin="5,5,0,10" Name="mainLabel" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

How can I make objects defined in xaml-file of DialogStandard accessible to the project where I'm referencing to the Lib where DialogStandard is defined?

Comment: Can you change the code/XAML of `DialogStandard`?

Comment: @nemesv Yes, that would not be a problem. I can change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get your `Label` if it has `Name` with the help of the [FrameworkElement.FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx) method:

```
DialogStandard newWindow = new DialogStandard();
newWindow.Title = "my title";
Label mainLabel = (Label)newWindow.FindName("mainLabel");
mainLabel.Content = "my label";
```